# SwiftUI CoreData: How to show multiple fetchedresults in one list sorted by a creationDate

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have 2 FetchRequest for my CoreData entities in my view. Each of this entities has a `creationDate: Date` and a `id: UUID`.
Now I would like to show both `fetchedResults` in one List, does anyone know how this could work?
In addition I would like to sort the list by the creationDate of the entities and verify them by their Id.

This is my code at the moment:

```
struct HomeListView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: TimerObject.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TimerObject.creationDate, ascending: false)]) var timers: FetchedResults<TimerObject>
    @FetchRequest(entity: StopWatchObject.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TimerObject.creationDate, ascending: false)]) var stopWatches: FetchedResults<StopWatchObject>
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
    
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
}
```

I would be very happy to hear from you, greetings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043204/iterating-over-multiple-arrays-with-foreach-swiftui or create a computed property that combines the entities somehow

Comment: @ChrisR the first sollution works but if the count of the two fetchedresults are different, the forEach won´t be run. Any other ideas?

Comment: do you want to edit the entries in some detailView, or do you just want to display them? If edit – I don't see a way, because you then need access to their different types. If show – you could translate both entities into a computed var array, that feeds the ForEach. --- OR: change the CoreData model, so they are one entity with some property defining them as timer vs stopwatch.